# Use SceneKit to open .dae file on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, scenekit

I want to go to download the 3D file(.dae),and open ，But failed, according to the following tips：SceneKit IO: error, COLLADA files are not supported on this platform.

I find some answer on the Internet, some people say that you need to perform some script file，Is the means that the server must use Mac，Who knows what other else？

I am searching for a long time on net. But no use. Please help or try to give some ideas how to achieve this

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to import your `.dae` file onto the scene. As I know, Xcode will convert your `.dae` file to SceneKit's internal file format

Answer (score 1):

According to [this post](http://www.the-nerd.be/2014/11/07/dynamically-load-collada-files-in-scenekit-at-runtime/), you cannot directly import `.dae` files on runtime. You should convert your `.dae` files to `.scnassets`.

You have 2 options:

1. Convert your `.dae` files before upload to server. So, there is no need to have mac server.
2. Order mac server, configure your server to convert all COLLADA files automatically.